# How to print USD Price from My JSON?

Tags: arrays, json, arraylist

I have data like this

```
[
{
    "id": "ethereum", 
    "name": "Ethereum", 
    "symbol": "ETH", 
    "rank": "2", 
    "price_usd": "449.935", 
    "price_btc": "0.0574132", 
    "24h_volume_usd": "1632850000.0", 
    "market_cap_usd": "44300619222.0", 
    "available_supply": "98460042.0", 
    "total_supply": "98460042.0", 
    "max_supply": null, 
    "percent_change_1h": "0.11", 
    "percent_change_24h": "-2.69", 
    "percent_change_7d": "-21.25", 
    "last_updated": "1522211054"
}
```

]

Anyone can help me to print USD Price? Like this...
USD Price: 449.935

Comment: it's not really clear what you want. Please be more specific. Read this "how do I ask a good question?" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just looking for `data[0].price_usd`?

```js
var data = [
{
    "id": "ethereum", 
    "name": "Ethereum", 
    "symbol": "ETH", 
    "rank": "2", 
    "price_usd": "449.935", 
    "price_btc": "0.0574132", 
    "24h_volume_usd": "1632850000.0", 
    "market_cap_usd": "44300619222.0", 
    "available_supply": "98460042.0", 
    "total_supply": "98460042.0", 
    "max_supply": null, 
    "percent_change_1h": "0.11", 
    "percent_change_24h": "-2.69", 
    "percent_change_7d": "-21.25", 
    "last_updated": "1522211054"
}];

console.log('USD Price: ' + data[0].price_usd);
```